# how to run sql script file in sqlite3 through objective-C

Tags: objective-c, sqlite

Here is my question, when interacting with Sqlite 3 through terminal, you can execute SQL statements stored in a txt file by executing this command:

```
 .read filename
```

Is there a way to do such thing through Objective-C code? i.e. I've got a sqlite3 db file connected in the code, and i'd like to run a script file programmatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could forward the content of the file line by line, or in whole to the function [exec](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/exec.html)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, so, I guess that means I'll have to read the file into string myself and exec the whole lot as one big SQL statement then?

Comment: That is the only solution I see that is feasable to do. I also thought about controlling the stdin of the process and pass the command .read into it but I was not sure wather this will work. You can try it but as I said not sure if it works.

Comment: Thanks, I tried running the script in one go but it didn't work. Then I read in the file and execute line by line, bingo! Thanks again.

Comment: How did you end up doing this "line-by-line"?

Comment: @rckehoe: This only works if one line is a complete statement. Then read in one line from file and pass is to exec. Or Read the complete content of a file and pass the whole string to exec (if not too big)

Answer (score 6):

I know this is a really old question. I just thought I'd leave the code that i used just in case someone else would find it useful

```
-(BOOL)execFile:(NSString*)filepath
{
    NSError* error;
    NSString* content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filepath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
    if(error)
    {
        return NO;
    }
    char* execError;
    int x = sqlite3_exec(_database, [content UTF8String], nil, nil, &execError);
    if(execError)
    {
        NSLog(@"%s", execError);
    }
    return x == SQLITE_OK;
}
```